# googlemapのembed API(place)でのピン表示

Tags: google-maps

googlemapでembed APIを使用していますが、chromeの同期状況・座標によってピンが表示されないことに気づきました。

**どういう状況か**

placeモードを使用し、qパラメータに「座標」を指定すると....

皇居 zoom=13以上 且つ chrome同期中だとピンが表示されない

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={API-KEY}&amp;q=35.685850,139.751729&amp;zoom=13" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

京都御所 zoom値 chrome同期状態にかかわらずピンが表示される

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={API-KEY}&amp;q=35.025677,135.762135&amp;zoom=13" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

という状況でした。
経度が関係しているかと思い、名古屋城・駿府城・小田原城といろいろな地点で試してみましたが

zoom=13以上 且つ chrome同期中だとピンが表示されない西端

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={API-KEY}&amp;q=35.240570,139.146&amp;zoom=13" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

zoom値 chrome同期状態にかかわらずピンが表示される東端

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={API-KEY}&amp;q=35.240570,139.145&amp;zoom=13" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

という境目が見つかりました。
*緯度についてはあまり調べていません。*

**知りたいこと**

1. googlemapのembed apiで、qに緯度経度を指定した場合にchrome同期状態、zoom値、座標値によってピンが表示されないことがあるのは仕様でしょうか。
2. この仕様になったのはいつごろからでしょうか。たしか去年の今頃は、正しくピンが表示されていたように思います。
3. qに緯度経度を指定すること自体がgooglemap仕様外のことなのでしょうか。
4. qに緯度経度を指定し、ただしくピンを表示させるために、なにか方法はありますか。(ないのであれば、qに緯度経度以外の情報を指定するようにしようと思います...割と手間がかかりそうなのでできれば緯度経度を使用したいんですけどね...)

ちなみに
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide
ここで、開発者ツールでiframeのsrcを書き換えると、今回の状況を容易に試せます。